# How to configure Tomcat 8 as a go-between proxy?

Tags: java, tomcat, proxy

A Tomcat server on my server is running on port 8080. 
We are in need to use the Tomcat server to get user requests and forward those to corresponding proxy server running on another server (111.111.111.111:9090, user: XXX, pw: YYY).

So: We need to configure Tomcat to transfer requests to another server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box with Tomcat. It does not include HTTP reverse proxy functionality. You'd either need to find a 3rd-party module to do this (I'm not aware of any) or code up something yourself - e.g. using Apache HttpClient.